# How to invoke external command in gradle for Spring Boot project and eclipse IDE?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, handlebars.js

In my Spring Boot 2.0 gradle project I need to invoke the below commmand each time the bar.tmpl.html is modified and saved in eclipse IDE:

```
handlebars src/main/resources/static/templates/bar.tmpl.html -f src/main/resources/static/js/bar.tmpl.js
```

This command works when running in shell at the root of the spring project directory.

I want to automate this process while I am developing in STS eclipse IDE using devtools.  Each time an edit is made to the handlebar template file, project should be rebuilt running above command automatically.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom [exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) type task to run your command and make it execute [continuous](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continuous_build). Alternatively you can hook the task to a point in your lifecycle, for example the processResources task.

**Exec type task to run a command:**

```
task updateHandelbar(type: Exec) {
    inputs.files "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/static/templates/bar.tmpl.html"
    outputs.files "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/static/templates/bar.tmpl.html"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'handlebars src/main/resources/static/templates/bar.tmpl.html -f src/main/resources/static/js/bar.tmpl.js'
}
```

**Hook a task to any point in the lifecycle:**

Syntax: `<someTask>.shoudlRunAfter(<anotherTask>)`
Example: `processResources.shouldRunAfter(updateHandelbar)`

**Run a task continuous and wait for files to change:**

This will execute the task continuously. Means it reruns the task when the input files changes:

```
gradlew <someTask> -continuous
```

A combination of each code snippet may allow you obtain the expected behavior.

Comment: UnlikePluto I followed your answer but it does not work. The command handlebars is never run. Also even if this works eclipse IDE will not see the generated file unless I manually refresh eclipse project within eclipse as any change made to project files outside of eclipse, eclipse will not see it.

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: Gradle has nothing to do with any IDE or refreshing an IDE's resources. It runs compeltly independent of any platform. If you are dependeing on the Eclipse buildchain and not using Gradle, i.e. the gradle wrapper to run your application, no task will ever be called.

Comment: I run my app in STS eclipse. But to test your solution I run as you suggested  ./gradlew processResources -continuous

Comment: The statement `processResources.shouldRunAfter(updateHandelbar)` was intended as a example with the note to hook the task to a point in your project lifecycle where it fits. If your lifecycle isn't using the processResources task it will never be called. To test the updateHandelbar task you have to run `gradlew updateHandelbar`. I still don't know how you run your application. Do you have a run configuration in eclipse? Do you use `gradlew` on the comandline? What gradle task are you running to execute your application?

Comment: UnlikePloto Yes I tried running directly ./gradlew updateHandlebar  but same issue. it throws error: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 I run my app from within eclipse IDE just as normal Java app. I click on run icon it runs app successfuly sans handlebars issue. It launched embedded container and I go to localhostL8080

Comment: If your application is just a normal Java app in Eclipse and you rely on Eclipse's buildchain to execute your application without calling a Gradle task, i don't see the point of using Gradle in your project. You will not be able to hook `updateHandelbar` to any task this way since no Gradle task is executed in the first place. Anyways the problem you are having with executing `gradlew updateHandelbar` is most likely a wrong path for the inputs and outputs configurations. For the paths i used and tested the information you provided in your question.